# clamav - clamd error when setup as daemon (mac osx)

Tags: daemon, clamav, launchd

Issue:

Setting up clamav as a daemon process in mac osx throws some cumbersome errors and warnings while doing the setup and the documentation is good, but not perfect. I ran into some permission issues, file location issues, etc.

Things that are working:

- freshclam daemon via a cronjob(will post below)
- getting the daemon to load via launchd and show via `sudo launchctl list | grep clam`
- starting the daemon via launchd*

Things that are not working:

- clamd created from launchd plist does not stay in list after starting
- clamd starts, but returns the error below

---

***Error:***

***clamdclam.log:***

> ```
> ERROR: LOCAL: Socket file /usr/local/etc/clamav/clamd.socket is in use by another process.
> ```

***Setup:***

```
CONFIG_DIR="/usr/local/etc"
CLAM_HOME_DIR=~/clamav

# Make dir for configs in home dir
mkdir -p ${CLAM_HOME_DIR}

# Create configs
clamconf -g freshclam.conf > ${CLAM_HOME_DIR}/freshclam.conf
clamconf -g clamd.conf > ${CLAM_HOME_DIR}/clamd.conf
clamconf -g clamav-milter.conf > ${CLAM_HOME_DIR}/clamav-milter.conf

# Link configs
ln -nsf $(pwd)/freshclam.conf /usr/local/etc/clamav/
ln -nsf $(pwd)/clamd.conf /usr/local/etc/clamav/
ln -nsf $(pwd)/clamav-milter.conf /usr/local/etc/clamav/

# Test freshclam is working

# create freshclam a log file
sudo touch /var/log/freshclam.log
sudo chmod 600 /var/log/freshclam.log
sudo chown clamav /var/log/freshclam.log


# create Clamd Log file
sudo touch /var/log/clamdclam.log
sudo chmod 600 /var/log/clamdclam.log
sudo chown clamav /var/log/clamdclam.log
```

***Files:***

*All configs and functional files*

**`/usr/local/etc/clamav:`**

```
ls -l /usr/local/etc/clamav/
total 472256
-rw-r--r--  1 _clamav  admin       293670 Oct 10 17:35 bytecode.cvd
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user     admin           37 Oct 10 17:14 clamav-milter.conf -> /Users/user/clamav/clamav-milter.conf
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root     admin           29 Oct 10 20:48 clamd.conf -> /Users/user/clamav/clamd.conf
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user     admin        26784 Oct  9 16:46 clamd.conf.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 root     wheel            5 Oct 10 21:09 clamd.pid
srw-rw----  1 root     wheel            0 Oct 10 20:59 clamd.socket
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user     admin           31 Oct 10 19:25 clamd_run.sh -> /Users/user/clamav/clamd_run.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 _clamav  admin     56261254 Oct 10 17:34 daily.cvd
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user     admin           33 Oct 10 17:14 freshclam.conf -> /Users/user/clamav/freshclam.conf
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user     admin         7204 Oct  9 16:46 freshclam.conf.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 _clamav  _clamav         69 Oct 10 17:34 freshclam.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 _clamav  admin    170479789 Oct 10 17:35 main.cvd
```

mac osx plist file **`/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.clamd.daemon.plist`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.clamav.daemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/Cellar/clamav/0.104.0_1/sbin/clamd</string>
            <string>-c</string>
            <string>/usr/local/etc/clamav/clamd.conf</string>
            <string>-l</string>
            <string>/var/log/clamdclam.log</string>
        </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Crashed</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/test.stdout</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

---

***Currently Testing:***

- changed file ownership: was `user:wheel -> root:wheel -> root:admin`

`srw-rw----  1 root     wheel            0 Oct 10 20:59 clamd.socket`

Answer (score 0):

Currently with the above setup and configuration and changes of file ownership the error:

`ERROR: LOCAL: Socket file /usr/local/etc/clamav/clamd.socket is in use by another process.`

was solved with proper permissions to files and directories.